# Dynamic metadata according platform?

Tags: metadata, chef-infra, cookbook

Is it possible to detect the platform within the `metadata.rb` file of a Cookbook?

For example, something like this:

```
if node['platform'] == 'aix'
   depends "cats", "< 1.0"
end

if node['platform'] == 'ubuntu'
   depends "cats", "> 1.0"
end
```

But that is not possible since `node` is not available in that context. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, cookbook dependencies are entirely static. This has been discussed for some point in the future but no major proposals have emerged. If you are interested in contributing I would invite you to submit a [Chef RFC](https://github.com/opscode/chef-rfc/blob/master/rfc000-rfc-process.md) with a proposed fix if you can come up with one :)

The sticky point is usually that there are reasons for conditional dependencies beyond simply per-platform logic. This comes up often for things like runit vs. systemd, mysql vs. postgres, and apache vs. nginx.